# Socket over internet Python Embedded

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, embedded

I have an embedded system on which I can connect to internet. This embedded system must send sensor data to PC client.

I put a socket client using python on my PC. I put a socket server ( using C++ language on the embedded system because you can only use C++ ).

I can succesfully connect from my PC to the embedded system using the sockets and send and recieve whatever I want.

Now, the problem is I use local IP to connect to the system and both of them must be connected to the same Wifi router.

In the real application, I won't know where the embedded system is in the world. I need to get to it through internet, because it will be connectet to internet through 4g.

My question is, how can I connect to it through internet, if the embedded system is connected to internet using 4G?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Realistically in typical situations, *neither* a PC nor an embedded device hanging off a 4g modem will likely have (or *should* be *allowed*) to have externally routable addresses.

What this practically means is that you need to bounce your traffic through a mutually visible relay in the cloud.

One very common way of doing that for IoT devices (which is basically to say, connected embedded devices) is to use MQTT.  You'll find support in one form or another for most computing platforms with any sort of IP networking capability.

Of course there are many other schemes, too - you can do something with a RESTful API, or websockets (perhaps as an alternate mode of an MQTT broker), or various proprietary IoT solutions offered by the big cloud platforms.

It's also going to be really key that you wrap the traffic in SSL, so you'll need support for that in your embedded device, too.  And you'll have to think about which CA certs you package, and what you do about *time* given its formal requirement as an input to SSL validation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more easily solved if you reverse the roles of your embedded system and PC. If you are communicating to a device using IP protocols across cellular networks, it is much easier to have the device connect to a server on the PC rather than the other way around. Some networks/cellular modems do not allow server sockets and in any case, the IP address is usually dynamically allocated and therefore difficult to know. By having the device connect to a server, it "knows" the domain name (or IP address) and port to which it should make the connection. You just have to make sure that there is indeed a server program running at that host bound to some agreed upon port number. You can wake up the device to form the connection based on a number of criteria, e.g. time or amount of collected data, etc.